# How read a file on the remote node in Rundeck?

Tags: java, plugins, rundeck

How can I programmatically read the contents of a file placed in a specific directory on the node server?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an inline script in any job (aimed at the remote node) in the following way:

```bash
cat @option.mypath@/@option.myfile@
```

`@option.mypath` will contain the path and `@option.myfile` will include the file name.

And then save the content in a data variable defined in the [capture data log filter](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/learning/howto/passing-variables.html#passing-data-between-steps), let me post a job example to test:

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 942c867a-625a-459b-868f-645e6b34d564
  loglevel: INFO
  name: CaptureDataExample
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  nodefilters:
    dispatch:
      excludePrecedence: true
      keepgoing: false
      rankOrder: ascending
      successOnEmptyNodeFilter: false
      threadcount: '1'
    filter: 'name: node00 '
  nodesSelectedByDefault: true
  options:
  - name: myfile
    value: issue
  - name: mypath
    value: /etc
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - fileExtension: .sh
      interpreterArgsQuoted: false
      plugins:
        LogFilter:
        - config:
            invalidKeyPattern: \s|\$|\{|\}|\\
            logData: 'true'
            name: mydata
            regex: (.*)
          type: key-value-data
      script: cat @option.mypath@/@option.myfile@
      scriptInterpreter: /bin/bash
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 942c867a-625a-459b-868f-645e6b34d564
```